# How to compare the selected string from a listBox to another String in c#

Tags: c#, string, winforms, listbox, compare

For my windows forms application I tried to retrieve the selected string from a listBox and i wanted it to compare to a set string so that, in the event of the comparison returning true, i can set the next listBox to have specific, selection-related values.

```
    namespace PhysCalc
    {
     public class Selectors
     {
    public static string[] topicContents = new string[] { "MECHANICS", "THEORY_OF_RELATIVITY" };
    public static string[] VarItemsMechanics = new string[] { "Test", "Wavelength" };

    public static void SetVarBox()
    {
        PhysCalc.Topic.DataSource = topicContents;
        if PhysCalc.Topic.Items[PhysCalc.Topic.SelectedIndex].ToString() == "MECHANICS")
        {
            PhysCalc.Var.DataSource = VarItemsMechanics;
        }
    }
}
}
```

But somehow when i select "MECHANICS" in the listBox(in the code above named 'Topic'), the 2nd listBox(above named 'Var') just stays empty

any help would be very appreciated

Comment: What's `VarItemsMechanics`?

Comment: Sry for not posting that; it's an array which should be set as the DataSource for the 'Var' listBox

Comment: are you sure your `VarItemsMechanics` is not empty?

Comment: yes i am, here is the exact code:         public static string[] topicContents = new string[] { "MECHANICS", "THEORY_OF_RELATIVITY" };
        public static string[] VarItemsMechanics = new string[] { "Test", "Wavelength" };

Comment: There is no bug in the code you posted so with only those couple lines of code we can't discern much, we can only guess.

Comment: alright, i added the entire class, hopfully that can help you at helping me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties on the `Var` list control when using the `DataSource`.

If the DataSource is an object then `DisplayMember` is the object member it will use as the text display (which in your case is currently blank), and `ValueMember` is used to determine the `SelectedValue` property of the list control which is useful to bind against.

For example if your `VarItemsMechanics` is populated with the following class:

```
public class Mechanic
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you probably want to set the `DisplayMember` to `"Name"` and you *might* want to set the `ValueMember` to `"ID"` (subjective).

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that `VarItemsMechanics` is an Array of strings, so this doesn't work either, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if (PhysCalc.Topic.GetItemText(PhysCalc.Topic.SelectedItem) == "MECHANICS")
```

to this:

```
if (PhysCalc.Topic.Items[PhysCalc.Topic.SelectedIndex].ToString() == "MECHANICS")
```

Comment: In that case, see what `MessageBox.Show(PhysCalc.Topic.Items[PhysCalc.Topic.SelectedIndex].ToString())` gives you?

Comment: an error, frankly: "The best overloaded method match for * has some invalid arguments"

Comment: Hmm. The new code you posted doesn't look like it'll even compile... Assuming that PhysCalc.Topic exists and is a ListBox control, I don't see anything wrong with the MessageBox call.

Comment: Neither do I, but it somehow doesn't work out...Why should my code not compile?

Comment: Oh, I guess you're using the designer, so your Topic and Var definitions exist outside of your main code. Maybe try changing the MessageBox call to `MessageBox.Show((PhysCalc.Topic.Items[PhysCalc.Topic.SelectedIndex]).ToString())`?

Answer (score 0):

1- Bind your First List named "Topic" in the form_load Event

2- in the SelectedIndexChanged Event of your First List do your checks about the selected Item

and Fill the Second List

Here is the Complete Code and it works fine for me

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
         public static string[] topicContents = new string[] { "MECHANICS", "THEORY_OF_RELATIVITY" };
        public static string[] VarItemsMechanics = new string[] { "Test", "Wavelength" };


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.DataSource = topicContents;

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            switch (curItem)
            {
                case "MECHANICS":
                   listBox2.DataSource = VarItemsMechanics;
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hm, i tried your way, but it didn't work out either. i posted the entire changed class in google drive with anyone who has the linc being able to make comments, maybe you might take another look over it and comment whats wrong: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nGGBEuaV8KAMBYfmUwdCOuLzxoj_g3jg6rNyGtf4P5k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I looked at your code , you should put your code in the form itself , also the case statement MECHANICS word doesn't match the MECHANICS word in your data source , i tried create a windows application and fixed that switch case statement and it works fine for me

Comment: Isn't there another way than putting it directly into the form? I mainly put it in different classes for easier overview over everything, as there'll be even more things to code for selection later on. And I just tried putting it into the form class itself, that does not work either, frankly. Any other Ideas? Anyway, Thanks for your excellent help so far :)

Comment: Alright, i've encountered another error: I changed the contents of both arrays, but it still keeps the old values displayed... sorry if i'm being a complete and utter noob at this and upsetting you with that, but i appreciate your effort very much :)

Comment: In the selectedindexchanged event clear your second list before any line of code , list2.items.clear();

Comment: Thanks, but nothing's happening in the 2nd listbox now, meaning that it still remains clear after i selected it...

Comment: It's on the 2nd page:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nGGBEuaV8KAMBYfmUwdCOuLzxoj_g3jg6rNyGtf4P5k/edit?usp=sharing